# How I can find the next value?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

Given an array of 0 and 1, e.g. `array[] = {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, ...}`, how I can predict what the next value will be with the best possible accuracy?

What kind of methods are best suited for this kind of task?

Comment: You mean like pattern recognition?

Comment: Markov chains look appropiate.

Comment: Without a model: you can't (at least not better than random-guessing; or always picking 0). Without assumptions about the data (e.g. Markov-assumption like recommended by @wildplasser), each model is equally viable! Now it's your turn do describe the setting / data.

Answer (score 3):

The prediction method would depend on the interpretation of data.

However, it looks like in this particular case we can make some general assumptions that might justify use of certain machine learning techniques.

1. Values are generated one after another in chronological order
2. Values depend on some (possibly non-observable) external state. If the state repeats itself, so do the values.

This is a pretty common scenario in many machine learning contexts. One example is the prediction of stock prices based on history.

Now, to build the predictive model you'll need to define the training data set. Assume our model looks at the last `k` values. In case if `k=1`, we might end up with something similar to a [Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain) model.

Our training data set will consist of k-dimensional data points together with their respective dependent values. For example, suppose `k=3` and we have the following input data

```
0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1...
```

We'll have the following training data:

```
(0,0,1) -> 1
(0,1,1) -> 0
(1,1,0) -> 1
(1,0,1) -> 0
(0,1,0) -> 1
(1,0,1) -> 1
(0,1,1) -> 1
(1,1,1) -> 1
(1,1,1) -> 0
(1,1,0) -> 1
(1,0,1) -> 0
(0,1,0) -> 0
(1,0,0) -> 1
```

Now, let's say you want to predict the next value in the sequence. The last 3 values are 0,0,1, so the model must predict the value of the function at (0,0,1), based on the training data.

A popular and relatively simple approach would be to use a multivariate [linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) on a k-dimensional data space. Alternatively, consider using a neural network if linear regression underfits the training data set.

You might need to try out different values of `k` and test against your validation set.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [maximum likelihood](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaximumLikelihood.html) estimator for the Bernoulli distribution. In essence you would:

- look at all observed values and estimate parameter p
- then use p to determine the next value

In [Python](https://gist.github.com/miku/2810197551167a0d5a00041cbe01c0bc) this could look like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import division

signal = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]

def maximum_likelihood(s, last=None):
    """
    The maximum likelihood estimator selects the parameter value which gives
    the observed data the largest possible probability.

    http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaximumLikelihood.html

    If `last` is given, only use the last `n` values.
    """
    if not last:
        return sum(s) / len(s)
    return sum(s[:-last]) / last

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hits = []

    print('p\tpredicted\tcorrect\tsignal')
    print('-\t---------\t-------\t------')

    for i in range(1, len(signal) - 1):
        p = maximum_likelihood(signal[:i]) # p = maximum_likelihood(signal[:i], last=2)
        prediction = int(p >= 0.5)
        hits.append(prediction == signal[i])
        print('%0.3f\t%s\t\t%s\t%s' % (
            p, prediction, prediction == signal[i], signal[:i]))

    print('accuracy: %0.3f' % (sum(hits) / len(hits)))
```

The output would like this:

```
# p       predicted  correct signal
# -       ---------  ------- ------
# 1.000   1          False   [1]
# 0.500   1          True    [1, 0]
# 0.667   1          True    [1, 0, 1]
# 0.750   1          False   [1, 0, 1, 1]
# 0.600   1          False   [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
# 0.500   1          True    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
# 0.571   1          False   [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
# 0.500   1          True    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
# 0.556   1          True    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
# 0.600   1          False   [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
# 0.545   1          True    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
# 0.583   1          True    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
# 0.615   1          True    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
# 0.643   1          True    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
# 0.667   1          True    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
# 0.688   1          False   [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
# 0.647   1          True    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
# 0.667   1          False   [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
# 0.632   1          True    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
# 0.650   1          True    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
# accuracy: 0.650
```

You could vary the window size for performance reasons or to favor recent events.

In above example, if we would estimate the the next value by looking only at the last 3 observed values, we could increase our accuracy to 0.7.

Update: Inspired by [Narek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38806730/89391) I added a logistic regression classifier example to the [gist](https://gist.github.com/miku/2810197551167a0d5a00041cbe01c0bc#file-38805840-logistic-py).

Answer (score 2):

You can predict by calculating the probabilities of 0s and 1s and make their probability ranges and then draw a random number between 0 and 1 to predict.....

Answer (score 1):

If these are series of numbers that are generated each time after some reset event, and next numbers are somehow related to previous ones, you could create a tree (binary tree with two branches at each node in your case) and feed in such historical series from the root, adjusting weights (say a count) on each branch you follow.

Could divide such counts by the number of series you entered before using them, or keep a number on each node too, increased before choosing a branch. That way root node contains number of series entered.

Then, as you feed it a new sequence you can see which branch is "hotter" (would make nice visualization as heatmap/tree btw) to follow, especially if sequence is long enough. That is, assuming order of items in sequence plays a role in what comes next.